# About Texturing workflow

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow, baking, normal-map

I sculpted a model, I retopologized it, and also uv mapped it. Now I want to give texture and colour it.

How to begin? Should I bake normal,ambient occulsion maps first then texture the uv planes? Or the other way around?

Comment: hello, are you sure it will make a difference if you bake first?

Comment: I dont really know, that's why I am asking

Comment: You can bake the normals whenever you want, I'm not familiar with AO baking though, I guess it depends on how you want to use AO?